# How to send data from a datagrid row (form2) on click to another one in a usercontrol(form1) that have opened the form2

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

how can I send data after I click on the button "Ajouter ce Produit" as you can see and send the SelectedItem to the userControl in my Main form to its datagrid please Help!

this is the window that I open on the userControl and wish to copy from: 
[the image](https://i.ibb.co/tcg1ZPL/Capture-Form2.png);

this is the datagird in the usercontrol that I want to recieve the selectedItem in the window opened : 
[the Image](https://i.ibb.co/hRrG2YJ/Capture-Form1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could raise an event when you click the button in form1 and in form2 you could listen for that event and pass the selected item to form2.

```
   // The form that you want to copy the item from
public class form1
{
// This is the event that will be raised when you click the button.
public event EventHandler<ShareSelectedItemEventArgs> ShareSelectedItemData;

//This is where you click your button in form1
private void Ajuoter_ce_Produit_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 if(ShareSelectedItemData != null)
     ShareSelectedItemData(this, new ShareSelectedItemEventArgs() { ProductItem = (ProductItem)datagrid1.SelectedItem});
   }
}
// The form to send the data to
public class form2
{
    public form2()
    {
        // Listen for the event in form1 here
        form1.ShareSelectedItemData += (object sender, ShareSelectedItemEventArgs args) => ListenForItem(sender, args);
    }

    private void ListenForItem(object sender, ShareSelectedItemEventArgs args)
    {
        //handle the display of your item here.
        // The selected item can be accessed through args.ProductItem
    }
}

public class ShareSelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // This is the product item in your api or whatever you may have called it
    // it contains properties of price, name etc.
    public Product ProductItem { get; set; }

    public ShareSelectedItemEventArgs() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps. I find events very powerful in sharing data without breaking the concept of encapsulation.